# How can I make "complex" graphs that combine multiple functions with a software?

Tags: calculus, software, functions, precalculus, graphing

Til today I've been using geogebra to sketch functions for my students quizzes or homework. Sometimes I use the ones that I found searching in google, but this takes a lot of time specially because I have multiple courses and I need to diversify the tests, homework's, etc.  Recently I found this image:

[image]

It's there a way to make this type of graph quickly without having to define five different functions and so on?

Comment: This is easy in Matlab.

Comment: Can you link to a website to make it easy as you say?

Comment: [Try this](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=matlab+plotting).

Comment: [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BPiecewise%5B%7B%7Bx%5E2,+x+%3C+0%7D,+%7Bsin(x),+0%3Cx%3C%3D4*pi%7D,%7B1-cos(x),x%3E4*pi%7D%7D%5D,+%7Bx,+-5,+20%7D%5D).

Answer (score 2):

Have you used [Graph](https://www.padowan.dk/)? There, if you want piecewise functions, a quick way to do so is to select:  **Function** $\rightarrow$ **Insert Point Series**, and type the coordinates of a point. Exit that environment, and while holding **Select**, just click other points on your graph. You can choose how to connect them (linear, half-cosine, cubic spline) and later change this interpolation style with a click.

For the holes in the graph, you'd still have to write a formula (**Function** $\rightarrow$ **Insert Function**), specifying whether it "ends" at a point or a hole.

Note: This is a Windows application, though you can get to run on Mac with [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: Note: It's somewhat primitive and a little clunky (and my LaTeX friends show me no respect for using it), but it's fast, easily plots relations like $x*y=cos(x)-x*y^2+y^3$, and once copied into Word, you can double click to edit a graph.